# what effects does a court recording it's reasons for a judgement ? (India)

Tags: india

when a court is required to record it's reasons for a decision , what effects does it have on future cases ?

CrPc 354https://indiankanoon.org/doc/1266667/

sepecifically

> When the conviction is for an offence punishable with death or, in the alternative, with imprisonment for life or imprisonment for a term of years, the judgment shall state the reasons for the sentence awarded, and, in the case of sentence of death, the special reasons for such sentence.

does it mean they have to follow the same reasoning in every case ?

Answer (score 1):

It means that they have to provide reasons so an appellate court can review the decision. If they don't, the appellate court will remand the case for a statement or reasons before reconsidering the sentence on appeal.